# Jquery Accordion - Hide and show text in title element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a JQuery accordion where there is a possibility that text in the title section can be very long.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Title 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        Content 1
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Title 2 is really really long. Ideally, only a part of title 2 will be displayed here and the remaining text should be displayed when the accordion is expanded</a></h3>
    <div>
        Content 2
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Title 3</a></h3>
    <div>
        Content 3
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Title 4</a></h3>
    <div>
        Content 4
    </div>
</div>​
```

example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/865M9/

Is there a way by which I can display only the first 20 characters of the title when the accordion is closed and then expand the text to display the complete string when the accordion element is active (expanded)?

Comment: You know, jsFiddle has a panel to load most popular scripts as well as an option to choose when to run the plugin, `onload`, `domready`...

Comment: @elclanrs - Thanks for the tip. I was not aware of these features and will look into it the next time I create a fiddle :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can restrict headlines to one line with CSS.

For example:

```
.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmKu4/

Comment: Brilliant! I had considered using two separate <span> elements and showing/hiding them based on .ui-accordion-header active but your solution is elegant and what I had hoped would be possible. Many thanks for this!

Comment: Whats this do exactly? text-overflow: ellipsis;

Comment: @ViDesignz - Check the fiddle. You can see that the long string is truncated with a ... at the end. the ... is due to text-overflow:ellipsis

Comment: @user1: good question, I had fun tracking down my hunch about how to do this with CSS.

Comment: @VIDesignz: the "whitespace: nowrap" says to leave all the text in that box on one line (even if it doesn't fit... instead of wrapping it to multiple lines), then "overflow: hidden" says to hide the part that now sticks out of the right end of the box, and "text-overflow: ellipsis" just makes it look cool, by adding an ellipsis if the text gets trunkated.